# Java method on odd digits extraction

Tags: java

Write a method extractOddDigits() which extracts the odd digits from a positive number n, and
combines the odd digits sequentially into a new number. The new number is returned back to the
calling method. If the input number n does not contain any odd digits, then returns -1. 
For examples, if
n=1234567, then 1357 is returned; and if n=28, then –1 is returned.

Test cases:

```
(1) n : 12345; 
(2) n : 54123; 
(3) n : 246; 
(4) n : -12 (give an error message)
```

Expected outputs:

```
(1) oddDigits = 135; 
(2) oddDigits = 513; 
(3) oddDigits = -1; 
(4) oddDigits = Error input!!
```

This is the method i have done, but the output is

```
(1) oddDigits = 135; 
(2) oddDigits = 513; 
(3) oddDigits = -1; 
(4) oddDigits = -1
```

The last output should be Error input!

```
public static long extractOddDigits(long n){


String output = "";
if(n < 0) // check if negative
{   
    output = "Error Input!!";

}
if(n % 2 == 0){ //check even

    output = "-1";
}

while(n > 0) { 
   int left = (int) (n % 10);
   if(left % 2 != 0)    
     output = left + output;
     n /= 10;
}
System.out.println("oddDigit = " + output);
 }
```

How to i check if n is a negative number then goes to Error input?

Comment: This is homework? As a hint, while you can do that with integers alone, it's probably easier to use `Integer.toString()` to turn the number into a string, collect the odd digits and use `Integer.parseInt()` to get the result.

Comment: Well, this is cheap to return an error if this is negative, this would have been a nice usage of `&` here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all just because number is even, it does not imply that it does not contain any odd digits.

So:

```
if(n % 2 == 0){ //check even

    output = "-1";
}
```

is wrong. Also you dont need to type cast the `(n % 10);` to int.

You can keep a boolean variable `foundOdd`, that keeps track of whether so far we have found any odd digits, and in the end if that remains false, we can simply print -1.

So the right code is:

```
int n = 246;
String output="";
boolean foundOdd=false;
if(n < 0) // check if negative
  output = "Error Input!!";    
else
{
  while(n > 0)
    { 
      int left =  (n % 10);
      if(left % 2 != 0)    
      {output = left + output; foundOdd = true;}
      n /= 10;
    }
}
if(foundOdd)
  System.out.println("oddDigit = " + output);
else System.out.println(-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the first two `if` may assign a value to output, but not in a exclusive way, you can find a numer which is negative AND is also even AND it contains odd numbers. So you must ensure your code isolates each option.

Besides, your requirements say that the method must return the number, not just print it, so you method should be returning `long` and not `void`, but I'll leave that as part of your homework ;)

```
public static void extractOddDigits(long n){

  String output = "";
  if(n < 0) {   
    output = "Error Input!!";

  } else {

    while(n > 0) { 
      int left = (int) (n % 10);
      if (left % 2 != 0) {
        output = left + output;
      }
      n /= 10;
    }
  }
  if (output.equals("") {
    output="-1";
  }
  System.out.println("oddDigit = " + output);
}
```

Comment: The "Even-Check" is no requirement. (Didn't downvote, though.)

Comment: `n` being even doesn't means it is not containing odd digits.

Comment: The test cases are incomplet but OP says `extracts the odd digits from a positive number n` so indeed, this `n%2 == 0` is not necessary, and wrong too. (no -1 from me either ;) ) : EDIT : +1 ;)

Comment: @Pablo theres no problem in accepting someone's edit :p

Comment: @jackjay I did not reject it, I think it was automatically rejected because we both edited at the same time. I noticed your edition after I did mine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

when `n=-12`, you are assigning `output` "`Error Input!!`"

and then since also `n%2==0,` you are overwriting `output` to "`-1`"

Also, your logic -  if n is divisible by 2 , it will not have odd digits, is incorrect

Comment: Explain you code since this is only 4letters different ;)

Comment: @jackjay Yes there is - if it's negative.

Comment: oh LOL i didnt expect the solution is only thaaaat OMG thank you

Comment: Hint: `n%2 == 0` doesn't mean the number contains no odd digits. Test case: 12

Comment: @Fildor no use of `n%2==0` here.

Comment: @jack jay That test shouldn't be done if n is < 0 in the first place. So we both are correct.

Comment: You are assigning output twice once, as "Error Input" then overwriting it with -1. (Correction: don't use Mithileshs answer, but make sure you are no overwriting your first result.

Comment: @Anders I guess you mean to comment the question, not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This code checks for all digits if it contains any even one.

```
public static void extractOddDigits(long n){        
        String output = "";     
        if(n < 0) // check if negative
        {   
            output = "Error Input!!";
        }
        else {      
            //Iterate through the digits
            while(n>0){
                long lastDigit = n%10;
                if(lastDigit % 2 != 0) { //for odd digit
                    output = lastDigit+output;
                }
                n = n/10;
            }
        }   

        //If no odd digits
        if(output.equals("")) {
            output = "-1";
        }
        System.out.println(output);     
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want the method to run further if n < 0, then ,

```
 if(n < 0) // check if negative
 {   
    output = "Error Input!!";
    System.out.println(output);
    return;

 }
```

Comment: `return;` will return from function without printing `Error Input!`. Are you sure what are you suggesting or want to make edits before someone downvotes you.

Comment: Oh sorry! I meant to write a print statement there. Let me edit.